# Реализовать программу, которая сначала запрашивает у пользователя стили для текста, а потом выводит текст с указанными стилями

Tags: c++, char, битовые-операции

Нужно написать программу с такими условиями :

> Реализовать программу, которая сначала запрашивает у пользователя
>   стили для текста, а потом выводит текст с указанными стилями.
>   Стили храните в одной переменной типа unsigned char, которая занимает
>   8 бит.
>   Распределяете характеристики по битам следующим образом:
>   7 - в верхнем регистре или нет
>   6 - буквы через пробел или нет
>   5 - после текста добавлять \n или нет
>   4 - ничего
>   3, 2, 1, 0 - цвет (от 0 до 15)
>   Вам необходимо будет реализовать следующие функции:
>   + установка бита в указанное значение по индексу
>   + чтение бита по индексу
>   + установка цвета в последние 4 бита
>   + функция для добавления пробелов после каждого символа
>   + функция для вывода текста на экран с указанными стилями

При этом, хранить стили не в char-массиве, а именно в некой переменной типа unsigned char. Я даже не представляю то, как хранить в одной переменной стили. Либо условий я не понимаю, либо я не знаю, какого это - хранить стили в одной переменной. Может кто поможет уяснить, как мне это организовать? При этом, через битовые операции.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char styles = 0;
...
void setUppercase()
{
    styles |= (1<<7);
}

void clrUppercase()
{
    styles &= ~(1<<7);
}

bool isUppercase()
{
    return styles&(1<<7);
}
```

Примерно так...

Можно воспользоваться битовыми полями - типа

```
struct {
    unsigned char uppercase:1;
    unsigned char spaces:1;
} styles;
```

но это выходит за рамки поставленного вам условия.

Comment: Не понимаю программу. Можете пояснить мне, что происходит в этих функциях, если не составит труда? Битовые операции я прошёл совсем недавно, но тема не далась мне хорошо.

Comment: В приведенных функциях устанавливается (выставляется равным 1, не затрагивая прочие биты) 7 бит, он же сбрасывается (выставляется равным 0, не затрагивая прочие биты), и проверяется значение 7 бита. `(1<<7)` дает битовую маску, в которой установлен только 7 бит, т.е. число с бинарным представлением `10000000`. ну, а дальше с ним выполняются нужные манипуляции...

Comment: @Novy,  если  вы изучали тему и при этом не понимаете  простые операции, то  вам нужно взять учебник и  изучать до тех пор, пока все не прояснится

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

enum Style {c1 = 1, c2, c3 = 4, c4 = 8, v = 16, e = 32, sp = 64, u = 128, end};
Style& operator ++(Style& s)
{
    switch (s)
    {
    case  Style::c1:  s = Style::c2;  break;
    case  Style::c2:  s = Style::c3;  break;
    case  Style::c3:  s = Style::c4;  break;
    case  Style::c4:  s = Style::v;   break;
    case  Style::v :  s = Style::e;   break;
    case  Style::e :  s = Style::sp;  break;
    case  Style::sp:  s = Style::u;   break;
    case  Style::u :  s = Style::end;  break;
    }

     return s;
}

int main()
{   
    Style style = c1;
    unsigned char s {};
    while (style != Style::end) {
        s |= style;
        cout << "style added : " << s <<" == " << std::bitset<8>(s) << endl;
        ++style;
    }
    // проверка
    cin >> s;
    if (s & Style::c2) {
        // установить цвет c2
        cout << "ok";
    }
    else {
        // делать что то другое
        cout << "what to do next?";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. это не решение конкретной задачи, а следует цель, дать вам  идею, как решить свою задачу. Решать всю задачу за вас, не пойдет вам на пользу...

Comment: Что значит :: рядом с объектом структуры? А условие s & Style::c2?

Comment: Это означает  c2  из области видимости  Style.  Это не структура, а перечисляемый тип. Основная цель использования такого типа: придать битам имена.

Comment: А bitset<8>? Я таких не знаю..

Comment: не знаете, не используйте, просто так легко  получить биты. Я для примера написал.  Это стандартный класс для битовых операций. Изучайте, он очень  полезен во многих случаях